# Unable to display a form - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was trying out the tutorial on this link to create a form :

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

But when I type in the url(after creating the files of `form.php`, `formsuccess.php` and `myform.php`) `localhost/codeigniter/index.php/form`, I get the error of `404 Page Not Found`.

I am new to Codeigniter. Can someone help me figure out the error ? Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Can u add your application directory structure?

Comment: u mean to say the path of my files ?

Comment: Yes. You should have files codeigniter/application/controllers/form.php
codeigniter/application/views/formsuccess.php
codeigniter/application/views/myform.php

Comment: yeah .. the path is `E:\WEB D\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\form.php` .. and likewise

Comment: Have you edited your config file with $config['base_url']  to point to http://localhost/codeigniter/ ?

Comment: Did you try renaming the file to `Form.php`?

Comment: yes .. I had edited my config file .. with $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter is an MVC framework so url hierarchy is processed a little different.

Can you access localhost/codeigniter/index.php?

No: Do you have the correct .htaccess files in place?

Yes: In your controller folder, do you have a file named Form.php with the following code:

```
class Form extends CI_Controller {
    function index() {

    }
}
```

Comment: yeah .. in my controller folder .. i have the file named `form.php` with the contents as mentioned by you ..